# Disable spell checking in Word document using VSTO

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

I am trying to disable spell checking in the currently active Word document using a VSTO add-in. I want to avoid saving the spelling errors in the document's Open XML markup.

I tried to use the `Range.NoProofing` property.

```
currentDocument.Content.NoProofing = 1;
```

The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.selection.noproofing%28v=office.14%29.aspx) states that this should be set to `true`, however, the property's type is `int`. I tried setting it to `1`, but it doesn't work (spell checking errors still appear in the document). In the debugger I see that the property is still set to `0` after the assignment.

How to properly use the `Range.NoProofing` property or is there any other way to disable spell checking in a Word document?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up ignoring all spelling errors before saving the document using the `DocumentBeforeSave` event.

```
this.application.DocumentBeforeSave += this.OnDocumentBeforeSave;
```

The `NoProofing` property seems to work properly when used on ranges which contain spelling errors.

```
private void OnDocumentBeforeSave(Document doc, ref bool saveAsUi, ref bool cancel)
{
    // Ignore all spelling errors in the document
    foreach (Range error in this.application.ActiveDocument.SpellingErrors)
    {
        error.NoProofing = 1;
    }

    // Ignore all spelling errors in content controls
    foreach (ContentControl control in this.application.ActiveDocument.ContentControls)
    {
        control.Range.NoProofing = 1;
    }
}
```